# How to measure the signalling speed of Gigabit optical ethernet?

Tags: signal

Signalling speed of Gigabit Optical ethernet is  1.25 GigaBaud . I tried some methods such as measuring the UI of the eye diagram on a sampling oscilloscope by sending some random test patterns , high-frequency , low-frequency and compliant patters and also tried using an ethernet tester . But I'm not able to generate any stable eye patterns even though our scope is rated at 10GHz and recently calibrated . Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: How did you trigger the oscilloscope?

Comment: Trigger was using frequency generator of 1250 MHz .

Comment: The same frequency generator that was generating the test signals?

Comment: No the signals were from an ethernet testpad (1 G optical data pattern ) and trigger was from a separate device .

Comment: Trigger on the signal you are measuring. It is completely unreasonable to expect a separate generator to provide coherent clock. Especially at such a high frequency.

Comment: You may need to purchase a software feature for your oscilloscope to test optical 1GigE signals and generate eye diagrams. Additionally, check and see if your oscilloscope manufacturer has any documentation on generating eye diagrams, since it may support generating them without additional software. What model oscilloscope are you using?

Comment: Be aware that the data you put in and the data on the line may be different, due to the encoding that's done (8 to 10 bit conversion with limits to number of same bits in a row, balancing of  1s and 0s, etc...)  - the extra 0.25 Gb is only on the line, not in the data at either end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get a timing signal from the same system that is generating the test patterns.

Even if two signal sources are nominally generating a 1250 MHz clock signal and a 1.25 Gbaud data signal, there is likely to be a small difference (on the order 10's of parts per million, or on the order of 1-5 kHz in your 1.25 Gbaud system) in frequency between them, and this will make one useless as a trigger for an oscilloscope measurement of the other.

Depending on what kind of scope you are using, you may be able to trigger from the data pattern rather than a separate clock signal.